# Не получается записать текст в файл С#

Tags: c#

Не записывает текст в файл=( Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

```
        string CurrentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt"))
        {
                File.Create(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt");
                using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    string text = "hello!";
                    byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
                    fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Где-то здесь `using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))` вылетает исключение о том, что файл занят другим процессом?

Это потому что здесь `File.Create(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt");` создаётся новый файл и без освобождения ресурсов следом к нему осуществляется новое обращение `new FileStream(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)`.

1. После создания нового файла необходимо освобождать ресурсы так `File.Create(Файл).Dispose()` или же так `using (File.Create(Файл)) { }`.
2. В данном случае в этом `File.Create(CurrentDirectory + @"\update.txt")` нет необходимости, т.к. `FileStream` с параметром `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` в любом случае создаст файл на следующем шаге.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ! Действительно, всё решилось:3